# Cannot access port forwarding outside of network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a home security system made from a Raspberry Pi and I wanted to be able to access it when I am not at home. So I set up port forwarding at the IP address 192.168.1.XX and I forwarded port 80. Then I set up a subdomain on [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org). All was fine and dandy until we changed our ISP. Now, when I go on the website while connected to my own internet, everything works as it should, however when connecting from a different network, it cannot connect. What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to update the FreeDNS address to match your new public IP.

Comment: But the public IP and the FreeDNS IP are the same already. I’ve already checked.